# Jquery, how to test for a mobile browser?

Tags: jquery, android, browser, mobile, cross-browser

How do you test for, for example, and android browser in Jquery?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to test for a mobile browser or one with a small screen?

In javascript I would write

```
var isSmallScreen = ((screen.width * screen.width) + (screen.height * screen.height))
                     <= ((640*640)+(480*480));
```

to see if the screen is smaller than something like 640 x 480.